# Selecting NULL as a value in a JOIN if there is no matching record

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have three tables in a MySQL database: a lookup table for languages, a lookup table for animals and a third table describing what each animal is called in each language.

```
Table: languages
language_id
language_name

Table: animals
animal_id
animal_code
animal_name

Table: language_animal_codes
language_animal_code_id
language_id
animal_id
language_animal_code
```

The languages and language_animal_codes tables are populated. I need to create a form for the user to populate the animals table. Of course, until the animals table is completely populated, some of the language_animal_codes.animal_id will be null.

I need to query a record containing what each animal is called in each language like this:

`SELECT e.language_name,
    ecc.language_animal_code
FROM language_animal_codes ecc, languages e
WHERE e.language_id = ecc.language_id`

The result set looks like this:

```
language_name | language_animal_code
------------------------------------
English       | cat
French        | chat
English       | dog
```

This gets me part way to what I want. I also need to know the animal_code from the animals table if a record exists, otherwise I need the animal_code column to be null:

```
language_name | language_animal_code | animal_code
--------------------------------------------------
English       | cat                  | Felis catus
French        | chat                 | Felis catus
English       | dog                  | NULL
```

This seems like it should be a common problem but I can't come up with anything that applies when searching for terms like join junction table on lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JOINS`. A sample query can be like:

```
SELECT e.language_name,
ecc.language_animal_code,
a.animal_code
FROM language_animal_codes ecc
INNER JOIN languages e
ON e.language_id = ecc.language_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN animals a
ON ecc.animal_id = a.animal_id
```

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT * FROM POPULATED_TABLE RIGHT OUTER JOIN SPARSELY_POPULATED_TABLE USING (JOIN_COLUMN)`